# Make text wrap around floated div

Tags: css

I have two DIV's, first DIV is an icon, second one is a long text, both floated left:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container
{
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.icon
{ 
    float: left;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}

.text
{
    float: left;
}
```

The problem is when I resize the browsers width to minimum, the icon stays on the first line and the text gets divided into 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc.. lines. I want at least some of the text stay on the first line, in other words, **I want the text to wrap around the icon if there's no more space left**. How can I accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply removing the "text" element would do the task.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    Text that you want to be wrapped can be written here
</div>
```

Comment: This + text-align: start; on the container worked out perfectly, nice and simple solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apply the remaining width using `calc` for the `.text` element like below.

```
.text
{
  float:left;
  width:calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

```css
.container
{
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.icon
{ 
    float: left;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border:1px solid #ff00ff;
}

.text
{
   float:left;
   width:calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="text">This is some text showing how it is woring for a loooooooooong text.</div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only change next element to display block and no float

```
.text {
   display: block;
}
```

you can add more margin of .icon

```
.icon
{ 
    float: left;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin:0 10px 10px 0;
}
```